# How to implement MVCC concept for materialized view in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

```
create materialized view mtview
as 
select * from table_name
with no data;

refresh materialized view mtview;

create or replace function refresh_mat_view()
returns trigger language plpgsql
as $$
begin
     refresh materialized view mtview
      return null;
end $$;


create trigger refresh_mat_view
after insert or update or delete or truncate
on table_name for each statement
execute procedure refresh_mat_view();
```

Comment: You cannot insert into a materialized view.

Comment: I mentioned insertion for base table not materialized view. After insertion means i meant to say after insertion in base table. So will you please tell me MVCC concept implementation here?

Comment: You mentioned nothing. MVCC works for materialized views like it does for tables. If you need more information, [edit] your question and describe what you want to know in more detail. As it is, the question is pretty meaningless.

Comment: I want to make it very simple. If two users want to access records for two different purpose, like one user want to insert large number of records at  the same time 
 another want to see records then both user should have access. we can relate it to concurrent access, but MVCC concept will be better option.

Comment: That is still too simple for me. Access to what? Are you confusing MVCC and permissions? Since a materialized view doesn't change when the underlying tables change, the question doesn't make much sense. You should [edit] your question and add some SQL to illustrate what you mean. Perhaps that is clearer than language.

Comment: `refresh concurrently` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually i have already tried concurrent refresh, which took more time. I want to optimize this problem, So will MVCC concept can help in this  mattter?